# sed XML parse select text between tags with special characters while deleting other blocks

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, sed, xml

I am trying to parse an XML which consists of blocks between `<JOB>` and `</JOB>` , I am parsing within a do while loop , while reading the block between `<JOB>` and `</JOB>` , I am also redirecting the block to a file while deleting it and quiting, I tried using the below command , but it seems to be selecting all the other Blocks within the same pattern as well , I am using the escape Characters for each Special character , but not getting the desired output , could you please point me out where I am going wrong :

```
sed '/\<JOB/,/\<\/JOB/!d;/\<\/JOB/q' /tmp/ftp_final >> /tmp/result_1
```

Text sample :

```
<JOB 
     ACTIVE_TILL="20141124" 
     APPLICATION="CTDS0320" 
     APPL_FORM="AFT" 
     APPL_TYPE="FILE_TRANS" 
     APPL_VER="6.1.01" 
     APR="1" 
     AUG="1" 
     AUTHOR="wyy" 
     AUTOARCH="0" 
     CHANGE_DATE="20190403" 
     CHANGE_TIME="141554" 
     CHANGE_USERID="ecsadmin" 
     CM_VER="610" 
     CONFIRM="0" 
     CREATION_DATE="20190328" 
     CREATION_TIME="105555" 
     CREATION_USER="singhm7" 
     CRITICAL="0" 
     CYCLIC="0" 
     CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0" 
     CYCLIC_TYPE="Interval" 
     DAYS_AND_OR="OR" 
     DEC="1" 
     DESCRIPTION="Processes Source data files FTP from Source System" 
     DOCLIB="/prod/appl/ctds/Doc" 
     DOCMEM="energent_billing_delta.doc" 
     FEB="1" 
     GROUP="@CTDS-BW" 
     IND_CYCLIC="START" 
     INTERVAL="00000M" 
     JAN="1" 
     JOBNAME="energent_billing_delta-FTP" 
     JUL="1" 
     JUN="1" 
     MAR="1" 
     MAXDAYS="0" 
     MAXRERUN="0" 
     MAXRUNS="0" 
     MAXWAIT="7" 
     MAY="1" 
     MEMLIB="Not in use for application jobs" 
     MEMNAME="energent_billing_delta-FTP" 
     MULTY_AGENT="N" 
     NODEID="vprv0320" 
     NOV="1" 
     OCT="1" 
     OWNER="ctds_energent" 
     PARENT_TABLE="@CTDS" 
     PRIORITY="AA" 
     RETRO="0" 
     RULE_BASED_CALENDAR_RELATIONSHIP="OR" 
     SEP="1" 
     SHIFT="IGNOREJOB" 
     SHIFTNUM="+00" 
     SYSDB="0" 
     TASKTYPE="Job" 
     USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N" 
     WEEKSCAL="BCD-Y">
      <INCOND AND_OR="AND" NAME="CTDS0320-ENERGENT-BILLING-DELTA-OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
      <OUTCOND NAME="CTDS0320-ENERGENT-BILLING-DELTA-FTP" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="ADD"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ACCOUNT" VALUE="ctds_energent"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LOSTYPE" VALUE="Unix"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LUSER" VALUE="ctds"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ROSTYPE" VALUE="Windows"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RUSER" VALUE="controlm@enbridge.com"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LPATH1" VALUE="/prod/appl/ctds/Publish/ENERGENT/*"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RPATH1" VALUE="/\Business Intelligence-Gas Consumption\Energent\Outgoing\Gas Consumption\"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-PATH" VALUE="Not in use for application jobs"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-USE_DEF_NUMRETRIES" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RPF" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-CLEAR_ALL" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-CONNTYPE2" VALUE="FTP"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-CONNTYPE1" VALUE="LOCAL"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LHOST" VALUE="Local"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RHOST" VALUE="hdq-nt164"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LPASSIVE" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RPASSIVE" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD1" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD2" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD3" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD4" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD5" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRANSFER_NUM" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE1" VALUE="A"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE2" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE3" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE4" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE5" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UNIQUE1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT1" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM1" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM2" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM3" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM4" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM5" VALUE="1"/>
    </JOB>
```

Sample Code(not complete) :

```
#!/bin/sh
set -xv
rm /tmp/result* /tmp/ftp_final
sed '/^$/d' /tmp/FTPJobs_table007.xml >> /tmp/ftp_final
lines=`cat /tmp/ftp_final | wc -l`
while [ $lines -gt 1 ]
do   
#typeset -i temp=`sed -n '5,5p' /tmp/jobs_xa_final | grep DESC | wc -l`
#temp2=`sed -n '5,5p' /tmp/jobs_xa_final | grep DESC`
#echo $temp
#echo $temp2
#echo "nodesc"
sed '/\<JOB/,/\<\/JOB/!d;/\<\/JOB/q' /tmp/ftp_final >> /tmp/result_1
JOBNAME=`cat /tmp/result_1 | grep "JOBNAME=" | cut -d"=" -f2 | cut -d"\"" -f2`
WORKSTATIONHASH="WA_SAGT#"
echo $WORKSTATIONHASH$JOBNAME >> /tmp/result_final
cat /tmp/header.txt >> /tmp/result_final
FTLSERVEROPENTAG="<jsdlfiletransfer:server>"
FTRSERVER=`cat /tmp/result_1 | grep "FTP-RHOST" | cut -d "=" -f3 | cut -d "\"" -f2`
FTLSERVERCLOSINGTAG="</jsdlfiletransfer:server>"
```

Expected Output :

```
WA_SAGT#MKT_AMER_FTP
 TASK
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jsdl:jobDefinition xmlns:jsdl="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/scheduling/1.0/jsdl" xmlns:jsdlfiletransfer="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/scheduling/1.0/jsdlfiletransfer" name="filetransfer">
  <jsdl:application name="filetransfer">
    <jsdlfiletransfer:filetransfer>
            <jsdlfiletransfer:downloadInfo>
                <jsdlfiletransfer:server>ws94mdm0</jsdlfiletransfer:server>
                <jsdlfiletransfer:localfile>/tmp/leonjob2.txt</jsdlfiletransfer:localfile>
                <jsdlfiletransfer:remotefile>/tmp/leonjob.txt</jsdlfiletransfer:remotefile>
                <jsdlfiletransfer:localCredentials>
                    <jsdl:userName>wauser</jsdl:userName>
                    <jsdl:password>{aes}Gt+aN5nGz5dUBNaS/TJHoab0qwDZzII4gQPBi8AhPz0=</jsdl:password>
                </jsdlfiletransfer:localCredentials>
                <jsdlfiletransfer:remoteCredentials>
                    <jsdl:userName>wauser</jsdl:userName>
                    <jsdl:password>{aes}G7Rhyk5NkonXiV3AVSQ8pjVXElHgU0tE1RUveivv0xA=</jsdl:password>
                </jsdlfiletransfer:remoteCredentials>
                <jsdlfiletransfer:protocol>SSH</jsdlfiletransfer:protocol>
                <jsdlfiletransfer:transferMode>binary</jsdlfiletransfer:transferMode>
            </jsdlfiletransfer:downloadInfo>
        </jsdlfiletransfer:filetransfer>
  </jsdl:application>
</jsdl:jobDefinition>
 DESCRIPTION "Added by composer."
 RECOVERY STOP
```

Regards,
Sriram.V

Comment: Obligatory warning: parsing [XH]TML with regular expressions [is a very bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1081936), extremely hard to do properly and very easy to get wrong. Can you not use a dedicated XML parser instead? In any case, we can't help you parse data you don't show. Please [edit] your question and add i) an example input and ii) the output you expect from that example.

Comment: Hi Terdon,Thanks for the quick revert , have included sample data and code as well , could you please suggest or provide pointers towards ways of doing it.

Comment: please add to your question, what output you expect?

Comment: Yes, please add the output you expect so we can know we are giving you the right solution.

Comment: If you reduce the code to just the minimal, complete code that reproduces just the problem you want help with and reduce your sample input/output to, say, 5 lines each instead of 100 (or whatever that is) then far more of us will have time and inclination to try to help you. `not getting the desired output` is NOT a useful problem statement, just like taking your car to a mechanic for repair and only telling them `it's not working`.

Comment: Have added sample output to the original question , I will be building this output from the other XML input , I tried using the XML Parser XMLStarlet , installed it and tried running :  [root@EU-HWS-LNX242 ~]# xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//JOB' -v './@JOBNAME' /tmp/FTPJobs_table007.xml /tmp/FTPJobs_table007.xml:127.5: Extra content at the end of the document     <JOB     ^

Comment: Your output is some other xml file with a lot of information we don't have and your example and your code doesn't give. Please add example, expected output and sample code that match each other, and which are minimal but still cover all cases. I know that is not easy, but without, it will be difficult to get good help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing `xml` with `sed`, `grep` or `awk` is complicated and error-prone. You should rather use specialized XML parsers, e.g. `xmlstarlet`.

Not sure exactly what your output should look like, but from your script I assume it is something like the following. This will output a list of `JOBNAME     FTP_RHOST_VALUE` for each `JOB`:

```bsh
xmlstarlet sel -t \
-m '//JOB' \
-v './@JOBNAME' \
-o $'\t' \
-v './AUTOEDIT2[@NAME="%%FTP-RHOST"]/@VALUE' \
-n \
/tmp/FTPJobs_table007.xml
```

Output for your example text:

```
energent_billing_delta-FTP  hdq-nt164
```

---

You might need to [install `xmlstarlet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855905/how-to-instal-setup-xmlstarlet-in-linux), e.g.:

```
sudo apt install xmlstarlet
```

Comment: Have added sample output to the original question , I will be building this output from the other XML input , I tried using the XML Parser XMLStarlet , installed it and tried running :            `[root@EU-HWS-LNX242 ~]# xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//JOB' -v './@JOBNAME' /tmp/FTPJobs_table007.xml
/tmp/FTPJobs_table007.xml:127.5: Extra content at the end of the document
    <JOB
    ^
`

Comment: Tried using an escape character as well :`[root@EU-HWS-LNX242 ~]# xmlstarlet sel -t -m '\<JOB' -v './@JOBNAME' /tmp/FTPJobs_table007.xml
/tmp/FTPJobs_table007.xml:127.5: Extra content at the end of the document
    <JOB
    ^
`

Comment: This means that your XML file is not valid xml, precisely at line 127, char 5. You will need to fix that. Your example from your question is valid btw.

Comment: Thanks for the quick revert PLumo , so there are multiple blocks of <JOB> and </JOB> within the file , this is first Block , I am trying to iterate over all Blocks and get  same sets of data each time within the Block, I checked on Line 127 and Character 5 , its start of the second Block.

Comment: I understand that, and my `xmlstarlet` code will do exactly that, but your xml file is not valid.

Comment: The issue is because the first tag in the input <JOB remains open for long and has multiple elements within it and we are trying to extract elements from it , I am now trying a Python Implementation with XMLPullParser and xml.etree.ElementTree .

Comment: no, that is not a problem. That is totally valid and works as expected. These "elements" are called attributes and are normal xml. But yes, python might be the better option if you have a more complicated task later on.

Comment: Hi pLumo , You were right , the input file was an extract from another file where sub tags were extracted from a main tag and once I used the same command in the main File it worked very well and returned all output ,if I want to extract only first occurrence , I was trying something like below , but it does not return each occurrence in an iteration :    `sed '/\<JOB/,/\<\/JOB/!d;/\<\/JOB/q' /tmp/ftp_final >> /tmp/result_1
for i in {1..16}
do
JOBNAME=`xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//JOB[`echo $i`]' -v './@JOBNAME' ~testhwa/FTPJobstable007.xml`
echo $JOBNAME